# unable to login into my github using pycharm

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to share a  project in the github using pycharm IDE, I can't login to it by providing correct credentials , I even changed my password twice but still getting the same issue, can anybody help me with the problem and its solution.

attached please find the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Do you use 2FA by chance? Such behavior took place in older versions due to 2FA enabled, please see the guide:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206537004-How-to-access-GIT-remote-repositories-with-2-factor-authentication

In order to resolve the issue when prompted for credentials, either enter the token as username and leave the password field empty or use the token instead of your password.

Or you can update to the latest version where IDE uses OAuth to login to GitHub